# Create Optical Illusion with Perspectives

Tags: materials, uv, camera, text-object, texture-coordinates

I want to achieve an effect like in the screenshots. The text is readable only from one specific perspective. From all other angles, the text is distorted. I'm trying to figure how to achieve this effect in Blender without spending days shifting around hundreds of vertices. Is there a way to "project" the text from the correct perspective onto the wall in the background? Thank you very much!

[image: Perspective 1]

[image: Perspective 2]

Comment: This should be working for you https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/226920/2214 ... if you need to match real camera position from photo use fSpy https://fspy.io/

Comment: Not sure but UV camera projection could do the trick, make sure to subdivide your meshes enough so that there is no distortion

Comment: Sounds like a job for Shrinkwrap modifier (“Project” mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enabled this add-on here:

[image]

you can go to add mesh -> landscape

[image]

Hit on Shading tab and add these nodes

[image]

choose a texture with e.g. some text

[image]

Hit on UV-Editing tab and select all vertices

[image]

Choose UV -> Project from view

[image]

Then you might get something like this, which you can "fix" with S -> to scale and G -> to move.

[image]

In shader tab, change repeat to clip

[image]

Result:

[image]

other example:

[image]

Comment: du maschine! 1000 dank! :D

Comment: Kein Problem, gerne! 