# Projection mapping terrain from elevation angle photo

Tags: photogrammetry

I am trying to recreate a riverbank [Note: not the fort/buildings]from an historic photograph:

[image: Upper Fort Garry and riverbank]

I'm having trouble finding a tutorial as the terms I'm using in my searches predominately bring up other kinds of projection mapping of terrain; it's all aerial views and DEM models from cloud GIS services. Here, I know I will need to create the geometry myself, but my efforts have not gone well:

[image]

Can anyone offer any advice on a workflow that might yield better results?

Comment: Probably you will find this projection useful https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/226920/2214 ... There is nothing to say about modeling ... manual work - sculpt terrain, add mesh primitives as buildings ...

Comment: @vklidu I probably shouldn't have cut out the buildings because that probably makes it seem like I wanted to model them, too (I do! And have, already from diagrams). However, as this was a fur-trading fort in Canada, its relation to the river in the foreground is really important. It's the character of the riverbank I am trying to reproduce. I will try sculpting as that will probably produce better, organic-looking, results. Thanks.